# где находится официальная документация javascript?

Tags: javascript, документация

Где находится официальная документация javascript? Нужен сайт-источник.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кроме указанных выше можно обратить внимание на [тыц](http://es5.javascript.ru/)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf - ссылка на официальную документацию из статьи о JS на Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

[Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript) - один из самых самых вариантов. 
Как такового единого **официального сайта** посвященному *javascript* нет, во первых потому что каждый браузер видит js по своему, и некоторые свойства есть в одном браузере, некоторые в другом.
@Владимир Мартьянов дал вам ссылку на спецификацию стандарта. Но опять же, браузеры по разному их реализуют